# How to fill in missing values to a data set?

Tags: distributions, python, missing-data

I have a picture from a very old archive. It is a list of tuples (var, percentage). The problem is that I have only the 13 top values, ordered on percentage.

In python I decided to write it as a dictionary.

myolddictionary = {'var1': 0.64,
'var2': 0.63,
'var3': 0.40,
'var4': 0.38,
'var5': 0.36,
'var6': 0.34,
'var7': 0.34,
'var8': 0.34,
'var9': 0.33,
'var10': 0.32,
'var11': 0.32,
'var12': 0.30,
'var13': 0.29}

Now, my intuition tells me that if I had the entire dataset, because of the very small percentages of the top values, it would look like a uniform distribution, or a normal distribution with a very high variance, because the number of vars can be more than 100. My initial thought was to just take sum of the percentages I have, take the difference from 100, and then divide it into that many new vars so that each one gets a percentage smaller than 0.29% (otherwise, they would appear in the archive, right?) and add them to the dictionary.

But then I thought that this might be a really stupid way.

What I actually want is to draw from a distribution where:
a)draws are not equally probable
b)the sum of all draws is what remains from 100 after removing the percentages in my initial list (95.01 in this case)
c)all draws are smaller or equal to 0.29.

Something like function superamazingdistribution(number_of_extra_draws = 0, sum_of_draws, range) where:

1)number_of_extra_draws is the number of extra draws I want to do, added to the minimum required so can reach the sum_of_draws using the minimum number of draws * range
2)sum_of_draws, the number I want to reach, in this particular case 95.01
3)a list [num1, num2], in my case [0, 0.29]

and it returns a dictionary (one of many possible I guess) like {var1: percentage1, var2: percentage2,...,varN: percentageN}, which I can loop through and add to my own dictionary.

Comment: Trying to fill a few values from a large dataset is hazardous enough. Trying to fill most of a large data set from a handful of known values is going to give extremely uncertain results. Nonetheless, the appropriate distribution to use is going to be highly dependent on what these numbers you have actually represent. Using a concrete example will get you more informed answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could many different distributions for your tail.

The shortest tail would be to have `var14` through to `var340` all equal to $0.29$ and `var341` equal to  $0.18$ since $327 \times 0.29+0.18=95.01$.

You could have a triangular distribution for your tail, making it roughtly twice as long.  For example have `varN` equal to  $\tfrac{2\times 95.01}{655 \times 656}(669-N)$ for $14 \le N \le 668$.

Or you could have various other possibilities, including tails of infinite length.